# как создавать класс с неймспейсом \app\controllers не зная его названия?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Нужно создать экземпляр класса, название которого может меняться (класс в своём пространстве имён)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо получить строку

```
$classname = "\app\controllers".$controller_arr[0];
```

А потом уже создавать экземпляр:

```
$controller_obj = new $classname;
```

Comment: Я уже разобрался, но вам всё равно спасибо!